# Entity with Timestampable properties is not working

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, api-platform.com

I'm on a fresh install of [API Platform (v3.2.7)](https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/releases/tag/v3.2.7) and I'm trying to implement [Gedmo's Timestampable](https://github.com/doctrine-extensions/DoctrineExtensions/blob/main/doc/timestampable.md) on the example *Greeting* entity. I first tried using attributes

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;

/**
 * This is a dummy entity. Remove it!
 */
#[ApiResource]
#[ORM\Entity]
class Greeting
{
    /**
     * The entity ID
     */
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    private ?int $id = null;

    /**
     * A nice person
     */
    #[ORM\Column]
    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    public string $name = '';

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    #[Gedmo\Timestampable(on: 'create')]
    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATETIME_MUTABLE)]
    protected $createdAt;

    #[Gedmo\Timestampable(on: 'update')]
    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATETIME_MUTABLE)]
    protected $updatedAt;
}
```

But that didn't work, so I've tried using trait

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Gedmo\Timestampable\Traits\TimestampableEntity;

/**
 * This is a dummy entity. Remove it!
 */
#[ApiResource]
#[ORM\Entity]
class Greeting
{
    use TimestampableEntity;
    /**
     * The entity ID
     */
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    private ?int $id = null;

    /**
     * A nice person
     */
    #[ORM\Column]
    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    public string $name = '';

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

In both cases the error is:

> An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[23000]:
> Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'created_at' cannot be
> null

I've also tried this that worked for me in the past

```
# config/services.yaml
    gedmo.listener.timestampable:
        class: Gedmo\Timestampable\TimestampableListener
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
        calls:
            - [ setAnnotationReader, [ '@annotation_reader' ] ]
```

and the error is:

> The service "gedmo.listener.timestampable" has a dependency on a
> non-existent service "annotation_reader"

I dont't if it has to be with the [deprecation of Doctrine Lifecycle Subscribers](https://symfony.com/doc/6.4/doctrine/events.html#doctrine-lifecycle-subscribers) in symfony 6.3

EDIT
I see this in profiler (doctrine), so I guess the 2 timestamps are set to `NULL` instead of the correct value

[image]

Comment: Have you tried tagging the field manually, using attributes? The trait uses annotations, that are on the way out regarding support (which might explain your second error). Latest Symfony / Doctrine versions no longer support annotations, and only use attributes.

Comment: yes, see my updated answer (first example)

Comment: You tried tagging the listener with a event_subscriber I don't know if this can be an issue.

Have you tried to debug the `AbstractTrackingListener::prePersist` function ?

Comment: Can you post your gedmo configuration and tell us which exact version you are using for gedmo/doctrine-extensions, doctrine & symfony

Comment: @DylanKAS API Platform v3.2.7 comes with symfony 6.4.1 and doctrine 2.12. I don't have any gedmo configuration. I just did `composer require gedmo/doctrine-extensions` and then tried to use `Gedmo\Timestampable\Traits\TimestampableEntity`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it working. I had to change the way the service is registered

```
gedmo.listener.timestampable:
    class: Gedmo\Timestampable\TimestampableListener
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: 'prePersist' }
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: 'onFlush' }
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: 'loadClassMetadata' }
```

Without setting

```
    calls:
        - [ setAnnotationReader, [ '@annotation_reader' ] ]
```

And the class with trait

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

use Gedmo\Timestampable\Traits\TimestampableEntity;

#[ApiResource]
#[ORM\Entity]
class Greeting
{
    use TimestampableEntity;

    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\Column(type: "integer")]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    public string $name = "";

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

One more piece of information: in order to make it work as I used to only API Platform up to version 3.0.9 is suitable. Later versions no longer work with the services configuration. (I guess it has to do with the event subscriber deprecation)

Now I have another issue with `PUT` request but that's for another post...